# Python unicode string to string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This gets the contents of the last div with class="title":

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
title = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title' })[-1].contents
```

When I `print(title)` it outputs:

```
[u'Harry Potter']
```

How can I get it to print just:

```
Harry Potter
```

I tried `print(str(title))` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **get the text** using [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
title = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title' })[-1].get_text()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather convert the unicode instead of getting a string object as @alecxe mentioned, you'll have to encode it.

`print(title.encode('utf-8'))` should work.  If you're still getting the square brackets, just do `print(title[0].encode('utf-8'))`